# Sql query based on variable value, need to ignore null variables and consider variables containing values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have 6 variable
A,b,c,d,e,f

result variable
Res1,res2,res3,res4,res5,res6

Any variable can be blank/null or contain value like 30.43, etc

Need to write a query which will behave like below:

*Condition 1*:
If a>=30 and b>=30 then 
Res1='True'
If variable b is null then condition should be
A>=30
And if variable a is null then
B>=30

Same like this if 
A,b,c,d,e,f are in condition thenrespective checks are to be performed, if any variable is null then we need to ignore that and consider rest variables. In simple words condition will be based on if variable is not null and contain values

Comment: First, which database product, and second, is this just variable manipulation? Or are sets and tables involved? Please provide a representative example of your data, and what the output should look like.

Comment: Cond1

If var a & b holds value(NOT NULL)

If(a>=30 & b>=30) then res1=’show’ else ‘hide’
Cond 2

If all 6 vars are not NULL

If(a>=30 & b>=30 & c>=30 & d>=30 & e>=30 & f>=30) then res6=’show’ else ‘hide’

If var a is EMPTY & othr 5 vars are not null then we need to ignore var a from conditioning, then it wil be

If(b>=30 & c>=30 & d>=30 & e>=30 & f>=30) then res6=’show’ else ‘hide’

In simple words, if a var is empty then we need to ignore tht frm cond & if it holds som value then it is to be consder in conds

I have SQL SERVER 2012.

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out your question properly, i assume that you have some variables and need to get the result by Some conditioning for those. 
I assume you don't know what syntax have to use in this case. Try this syntax with you variables

```
 (CASE WHEN [Your_Variable] IS NULL
  THEN [Assign Your Variable with Condition]
  ELSE [Assign Your Variable with Condition] END) AS [Your_Variable])
```

Comment: Let me simplify, two variables a and b, we need to check each variable if it is NULL, if not NULL then consider that variable in condition or else ignore it